# Cant insert values into DB

Tags: mysql

I have a simple query code that always gives me an error, no idea what could be wrong.

The code is:

```
INSERT INTO 'email' ('id','firstname','lastname','email') VALUES ('','Peter','Miller','test@mail.com');
```

And I get the following error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ''email' ('id','firstname','lastname','email') VALUES
>   ('','Peter','Miller','test@' at line 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the quotes from around the email table name.

Comment: Tried, then the error just goes on...

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''id','firstname','lastname','email') VALUES ('','Peter','Miller','test@mail.com'' at line 1

Comment: Oh, I missed that you had quotes around field names as well, you'll need to remove those too.  Only the literal string values you're inserting should have quotes around them.

Comment: Ok, now it works. I was literally doing it as the tutorial showed and didnt work, but now it does :) Thanks.